# c# linq filter group by max composite key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a linq query:

```
 var reports = await dbContex.ShoppingListPatientReports
                             .Where(report => patientIds.Contains(report.PatientId))
                             .GroupBy(report => new { report.PatientId, RecentDate = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(report.DateCreated) })
                             .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                             .ToListAsync();
```

it returns groups sorted in descending order by the composite key (PatientId, RecentDate).
Keys:

```
10004, 2021-02-03
10004, 2021-01-01
10004, 2021-02-02
10002, 2021-01-05
10002, 2021-01-06
```

can I somehow take only the groups with the largest key (PatientId, RecentDate)
i.e groups with most recent dates (In this example, the result should be two groups):

```
10004, 2021-02-03
10002, 2021-01-06
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that works for me:

```
await dbContex.ShoppingListPatientReports
               .Where(report => patientIds.Contains(report.PatientId))
               .GroupBy(report => report.PatientId)
               .Select(patientShoppingList =>
                        new
                          {
                            patientId = patientShoppingList.Key,
                                             //Grouping reports by created date and take group wiht the most recent date  
                             reports = patientShoppingList.GroupBy(report => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(report.DateCreated))
                                                                          .OrderByDescending(group => group.Key)
                                                                          .FirstOrDefault()
                          })
   .SelectMany(g => g.reports.Select(r => r))
   .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `Where` after your `GroupBy`:

```
.Where(grp =>
    grp.OrderByDecending(x => x.Key.RecentDate).First().PatientId == grp.Key.PatientId)
```

Full query:

```
var reports = await dbContex.ShoppingListPatientReports
    .Where(report => patientIds.Contains(report.PatientId))
    .GroupBy(report => new
    {
        report.PatientId,
        RecentDate = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(report.DateCreated)
    })
    .Where(grp =>
        grp.OrderByDecending(x => x.Key.RecentDate).First().PatientId == grp.Key.PatientId)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This query really works? Which EF version?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv It's untested; maybe it can't be translated..

Comment: So, test similar query on your side and you will be surprised. Everyone here knows LINQ to Objects, but LINQ to Entities is very limited especially in grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It will be useful for you. It works with list of elements, but I've never tried it with EF.

```
 var reports = new List<ShopingPatientReport>() { ... }
                             .Where(report => patientIds.Contains(report.PatientId))
                             .GroupBy(report => report.PatientId)
                             .Select(report => report.GroupBy(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(report.DateCreated))
                                                     .OrderByDescending(f => f.Key).First()).OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                             .ToList()
```